# What should be ideal value of corePoolSize and maxPoolSize in ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, multiprocessing, threadpool

when we are getting 200 requests per second and there is no any dependency for the resource in between the threads.

We are having following code currently

```
@Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor getTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        int maxPoolSize = 1;
        if(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()-4>1){
            maxPoolSize = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()-4;
        }
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        System.out.println("Thread pool size SaveThread : "+taskExecutor.getMaxPoolSize());
        taskExecutor.setDaemon(true);
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("SaveThread-");
        taskExecutor.initialize();
      return taskExecutor;
     }
```

Comment: How long to the tasks typically take? (to the nearest 5 ms)

Answer (score 3):

For rough estimation you can consider the following formula:

> number_of_threads = (request_processing_time_ms / 1000) *
>   number_of_request_to_handle

Example: you process request within 30ms. To handle 200 requests/s you need approx 6 threads + some buffer.

You need also to consider:

- this solution does not scale linearly (because of [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch))
- distribution of processing request time (statistically)
- gc pauses
- other processes on the machine
- etc.

The best way is to setup some performance testing executed from other machine than your software is running.